# How can I text-indent the start of a every paragraph apart from the first in css?

Tags: css, sass

As the title says I have a p element and I want to text-indent the start of every paragraph apart the the first paragraph where I don't want any text-indent. How can I do this in css?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bhushanwagh/62ratnwm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option which wouldn't require adding any additional markup or classes to your page: 
http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/jyaOJL

```
p{
  text-indent:20px;
}

body p:first-child{
  text-indent:0;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can give your first paragraph a class and then can do the following:

```
p:not(.first){
  text-indent:30px
}
```

Please refer to this link:https://jsfiddle.net/n5pjgev6/400/

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
p > span {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
p > span:first-child {
  text-indent: 25px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s8bL0v9a/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by applying a `text-indent` property to your paragraphs as so:

```
p {
    text-indent: 50px;
}
```

> *The text-indent property specifies how much horizontal space text should be moved before the beginning of the first line of the text content of an element. Spacing is calculated from the starting edge of the block-level container element.*

Excerpt from **[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-indent/)**.

Comment: thank you, but I didn't want text-indent on the first paragraph only the latter two

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/bhushanwagh/62ratnwm/)

```
    p{
  text-indent:40px
}
p:first-child{
  text-indent:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
p:not(:first-child) {
   text-indent:30px;
}
```